# How to reduce the elevation level of a com server

Tags: com, elevation

I have created a COM server "helper.exe".
I have an elevated ATL exe that creates and instance of one of it's interfaces.
Something like this:

```
CComPtr<IFileHelper> pHelper;
pHelper.CoCreateInstance(L"Helper.FileHelper");
```

I've discovered that the COM server ("helper.exe") runs with the elevation level of the process that executes the above code. I do not want this to happen. I would like the COM server to always run without elevation.

Are there any techniques I can use to make sure a COM server always runs without elevation?

Comment: In your helper.exe code, you should call CoInitializeSecurity and play with its parameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693736.aspx)